# Flutter Bluetooth Communication

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I'm trying to establish a Bluetooth connection between Flutter and an Arduino Bluetooth module (HC-06) using the flutter_reactive_ble package. I successfully scanned for the module, but I'm unsure about how to proceed with the connection. Even after going through the documentation, I'm still uncertain about how to establish a connection and exchange data. How can I connect to the HC-06 module using Flutter, and how can I send and receive data?

Additionally, I'm struggling to understand how to obtain the necessary IDs, such as characteristicUuid, for connecting and reading data. Can you provide guidance on how to retrieve these ID values?

Comment: Hey, the HC-06 is not a BLE device. It uses Bluetooth Classic (also called Blueooth Serial). Test this by using a Bluetoth Terminal App on your phone to connect to the HC-06. For your own flutter app the package [flutter_bluetooth_serial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial) should work